# MS Access, OleDbAdapter not deleting records but no errors

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I'm trying to delete the record containing the matching text that is displayed in a datagridview. I get the string all right and nothing seems to go wrong, but none of the records are being deleted.

```
String text;
int i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
text = (string)dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
String deleteSql = "DELETE FROM [Sugg] WHERE sugg_text='"+text+"'";
MessageBox.Show(text);
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this suggestion?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
        oleDbConnection1.Open();
        oleDbDataAdapter1.DeleteCommand = oleDbConnection1.CreateCommand();
        oleDbDataAdapter1.DeleteCommand.CommandText = deleteSql;

        oleDbDataAdapter1.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oleDbConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: You should use [OledbParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) to prevent Sql-Injection. Apart from that you should remove possible white-spaces from the string and carriage-returns and line feeds from the end of the it: `text.Trim().TrimEnd('\r', '\n')`

Comment: @TimSchmelter In regard to OledbParameters, if I have a some code:
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE ?";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = "a";
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

what does '@p1' signify? Column name? Arbitrary param name?

Comment: Albeit is a bit strange this code should work. Are you talking about record not deleted in the database or row not removed from the grid?

Comment: The record is not deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to remove the try/catch block to see if there really is no error.**

The fact you don't get an error probably means that either the content of your `text` variable is bad, or that the error gets lost in your try/catch block. (which we can't see completely)

Also as Tim said, instead of inserting your `text` value directly in the SQL statement, use **command parameters** for these kind of things. It will prevent unexpected things from happening, such as an apostrophe inside of `text`.

```
String deleteSql = "DELETE FROM [Sugg] WHERE sugg_text=@SUGG_TEXT";
var cmd = oleDbConnection1.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = deleteSql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SUGG_TEXT", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the following syntax.  The using blocks ensure you are cleaning up your connections / commands.

```
public void TestMethod()
        {
            string connectionstring = "someconnectionstring";
            string deletesql = "delete from table where something = somethingelse";
            using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                using(OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(deletesql, con))
                {
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Of course you need to add your try / catch blocks as well as wrap in a transaction to be complete but this should give you a place to start.